# Numpy 2D array sorted by unique first row values with corresponding maximum values from the second row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assuming a table like
1    2    1    2
5    3    3    8

I want to find a 2D array sorted by unique first row values with corresponding maximum
values from the second row. For the table above giving the result:
1    2
5    8

My actual problem is really large and a for loop takes ages. I guess this problem is efficiently solved using Numpy. Anyone who can help me?
For the test case the numpy array is:
a=np.array([[1,2,1,2],[5,3,3,8]])

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can refer to [Maximum values in y numpy array for corresponding unique values in x array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73994230/maximum-values-in-y-numpy-array-for-corresponding-unique-values-in-x-array), although no answer was accepted, all three answers were practical.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) the values in descending order and get the first column per group using [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
a2 = a[:, np.lexsort(-a, axis=0)]

out = a2[:, np.unique(a2[0], return_index=True)[1]]
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 8]])
```